# What is the syntax for counting number of rows in PHP Prepared Statement?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

In using PHP Prepared Statement, what is the syntax for counting number of rows?

---

> ```
> $stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); 
> $query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
>
> if($stmt->prepare($query)){  
> $stmt->num_row(); //SOMETHING SIMILAR TO THIS....  }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt->num_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysqli its [`num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php). Make sure you call [`store_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are using mysqli. If so, then [affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) should give you the number of rows will give you the number of rows returned by a `SELECT` operataion.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to add

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

before

```
$stmt->num_rows;
```